# Form->getObject() doesn't work anymore in 1.4.19?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I have the following code on my blog, to check if a comment is spam

```
  $tmp = new Comment();
  $tmp->setName(urldecode($this->getRequest()->getCookie('commName')));
  $tmp->setEmail(urldecode($this->getRequest()->getCookie('commEmail')));
  $tmp->setUrl(urldecode($this->getRequest()->getCookie('commUrl')));
  $this->form = new CommentAddForm($tmp);

if ($request->isMethod('post'))
{

  $this->form->bind($request->getParameter('comment'));

  if ($this->form->isValid())
  {
    $key = sfConfig::get('akismet_api_key');

    $data = array(
          'blog'       => '...',
          'user_ip'    => $this->getRequest()->getHttpHeader('addr','remote'),
          'user_agent' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
          'referrer'   => $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],
          'comment_type'         => 'comment',
          'comment_author'       => $this->form->getObject()->getName(),
          'comment_author_email' => $this->form->getObject()->getEmail(),
          'comment_author_url'   => $this->form->getObject()->getUrl(),
          'comment_content'      => $this->form->getObject()->getComment()
    );

    $isSpam = myLib::akismet_comment_check($key, $data);
    (…)
```

But I just noticed that I'm bombarded with spam, and while testing on local it seems that `$this->form->getObject()->getName()` doesn't return the name in the form, but the previous name used, the one saved in a cookie !

I looked at the changelog for symfony 1.4.19, but didn't see anything that would relate to that, it may be a coincidence.

Comment: How do you instantiate the form? `$this->form = new ?` And what does the cookie has to do with anything? Also, is this intentional or you forgot it there: `$key = sfConfig::get('akismet_api_key'); $key = 'mykey';`

Comment: You're right, that line is useless

Comment: I still need to know how you construct your form object. Because, as you probably already know, you need to send an instance of the object when the constructing the form. Something like `$this->form = new UserForm($myUser);`, where $myUser as an already populated User object  (so that $form->getObject()->getName() will return the name of the user)

Comment: I've edited my question : I prefill the fields with the value of the cookies, and when the form is sent I bind() the form to the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `$form->bind()` method only populates `values` property of the form. It does not hydrate the form's object. That is done when saving the form. You probably want to call `$form->updateObject()` which is called during save. That will populate the object with the form's values.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to have helped (but I don't get why, it worked a few days ago and I haven't touched it)

Comment: Now it's the call to Akismet that fails :( Well at least now it sends the right data.

Comment: Anything that we can help you with?

Comment: Maybe, I'm looking at the code, but it's a copy&paste of http://akismet.com/development/api/#comment-check -- fsockopen seem to always return false ; and Akismet doesn't seem down.

Comment: Oh I got it; the function uses $key.'.rest.akismet.com', and I deleted the line that set $key thinking I didn't need it anymore :)

Comment: Ok, so your back on track now? Please don't forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: Yes everything seems ok, I'll do a final check now